# How can i access a value that can be accessed from anywhere in the application?

Tags: reactjs

I am having a portfolio_id that i am setting while changing the route and am successfully able to access it. However, it gets lost when i refresh the page. I am passing it in props. Is there any other way where in i can access it any given point of time?

Comment: When the page refreshes, the react app gets completely reloaded. If you need to preserve state, you need to preserve state in local storage, via an api, or some kind of database.

Comment: Please add corresponding code.